# QT Error: Token " ' " is not a valid preprocessor expression

Tags: c++, qt5.4

The following error is what I am getting in what in alot of HEADER file  (qglobal.h, qchar.h, qnamespace.h, etc.)

Would be great, if someone could shed some light on it.

> error: token "`" is not valid in preprocessor expressions
>
> C:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\include\QtCore\qglobal.h:263: in expansion of macro 'QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE'
>    #define QT_DEPRECATED_SINCE(major, minor) (QT_VERSION_CHECK(major, minor, 0) > QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE)
>
> C:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\include\QtCore\qglobal.h:815: in expansion of macro 'QT_DEPRECATED_SINCE'
>    #if QT_DEPRECATED_SINCE(5, 0)

Comment: No more error lines from the compiler (e.g. for QT_VERSION_CHECK, QT_DISABLED_DEPRECATED_BEFORE)?

Comment: Werner : Thanks for the response. compiler output says  Makefile.Release:2494: recipe for target 'release/qextserialbase.o' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [release/qextserialbase.o] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'W:/TB-Exist/013_Software/Übergabe_2015/150130_Übergabe/001_qIMS/qIMS_bb/build-qIMS_bb-Desktop_Qt_5_4_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
makefile:34: recipe for target 'release' failed
mingw32-make: *** [release] Error 2
13:57:55: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw491_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project qIMS_bb (kit: Desktop Qt 5.4.2 MinGW 32bit)

Comment: Please don't put relevant stuff only in the comments. Also: in your comment I do not see the errors listed in your question, I do not see any detailed compiler errors at all!?

Comment: Werner : Right now my compiler output is - 16:55:59: Elapsed time: 00:02.

Comment: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw491_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't supposed to include these headers directly, and some them are not free-standing. Always include the official headers such as `<QChar>` or `<QGlobal>` which should work as expected.

Comment: James : Thanks for the response but as mentioned by you, this is how I have been including my header in the program "<QChar> etc.". But now where I have exclusively mentioned "qglogal.h", so kind of confused where is it accessing from by default.

Comment: Oh, my apologies for the confusion, this must presumably be related to your compiler / preprocessor then, but I am not familiar with different mingw versions.